# Webform address feilds are not populating from the querystring

Tags: webforms

I have a webform at http://safebuy.nz/New?your_name=John%20Argent&your_email_address=grub@hotmail.com&address=28%20smith%20Rd&address2=&city=&state_province=Northland&postal_code=&phone_number=0220492570&bank_account_number=

The address feilds are not populating from the querystring.

This page is also showing a date at top of form that shouldnt be there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to target the composite address element's sub-elements.

[http://safebuy.nz/New?your_address[address]=28%20smith%20Rd&your_address[address2]=&city=&your_address[state_province]=Northland&your_address[postal_code]=&phone_number=0220492570](http://safebuy.nz/New?your_address%5Baddress%5D=28%20smith%20Rd&your_address%5Baddress2%5D=&city=&your_address%5Bstate_province%5D=Northland&your_address%5Bpostal_code%5D=&phone_number=0220492570)

Comment: Yes that works perfect. Any idea why the random date at the top of the form and how to remove it?

Comment: The date is the node created timestamp. It can be removed via the theme settings or templates